# Combine two excel documents with imported data and pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel documents. Each has a sheet with imported data from web and a sheet that contains a pivot table based on the imported data and chart summarizing that pivot table.
I want to combine both to see them on a single chart signifying the difference between the two.

Comment: Are you looking for a one time solution, or a way of automating the process so that it can easily be repeated?

Comment: One time solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided and assuming that the web data is similar in structure:

1. open a new workbook
2. name the first worksheet "data"
3. in data label a the first column "source"
4. copy the contents of the data from the web worksheet from the first workbook
5. paste into "data" cell b1
6. in column 1 of data place "first" in all of the cells in the source column for which you pasted data in, use fill down
7. copy the contents of the data from the web worksheet from the second workbook
8. paste into "data" below the data already there
9. in column 1 of data place "second" in all of the cells in the source column for which you pasted data in, use fill down
10. now create a pivotchart from the "data" worksheet and use "source" to compare the two

Answer (score 0):

I would add both tables into an Excel Model using Power Pivot.  In Power Pivot you can define the relationship between the two tables, and define the calculation of the "difference between the two".

Then you can build a Pivot Table and Pivot Chart combining data from both tables and showing the calculation.